# Will adding a resistive load to a lighting circuit stop my electronic dimmer from leaking current to my LEDs?

Tags: led, dimmer, lightning

I changed my bedroom lights yesterday for 220V 7W dimmable LED lights.

My bedroom dimmer is an electronic type (LightwaveRF).

In the pitch black, last night, I could see the lights faintly glowing/flickering slightly.

I wondered if adding a resistive load to the circuit would help prevent this? It seems like the dimmer is somehow passing current to the lights even when off?

I've found a [resistive load on Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Danlers-RESLOADE-DANLERS-Load-Resistor/dp/B00MEDBE0Q/ref=sr_1_18?crid=1626RJ45KSEYX&dchild=1&keywords=resistive+load+for+led+lights&qid=1596439592&sprefix=led+resistive+lo%2Caps%2C171&sr=8-18)

Would this work? Or is there a better alternative fix? Thanks

Comment: Just buy a dimmer with a definite off position so that this is avoided.

Comment: @Andyaka the dimmer I have is controllable through Google Home etc and so needs to be one that doesn't have the "mechanical" off position. But I did consider doing that if it becomes too much hassle to try and rectify the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Andy aka is right. Adding a resistive load in parallel with your LEDs will make the LEDs slightly dimmer, but you will still have the same issue. Only now when something goes wrong you can't blame the manufacturer.

Comment: @Stiddily I was hoping to avoid it but, if it's the only way then I will.

Comment: @JohnT Your LED lights aren't compatible with the dimmer you have, assuming that the dimmer does at least work on some kinds of lights. For example, I bought some dimmers from Costco years ago, before the advent of LED lights. These specifically said they would NOT work well with fluorescent lighting. And in fact, they don't work well with them. Just as they said. (I tried, to see.) Not all dimmers work (or play well) with all light types. You need to properly match one with the other. As you are stuck with your LightwaveRF dimmer, read its manual carefully about what it supports.

Comment: @JohnT (Or else read the "dimmable" LED light manual to find out the kinds of dimmers they work with. That might give you a clue about why things aren't working, between the two manuals. The fact is, though, that properly matched controllers and the devices they properly support should work properly together. So if you find that both manuals support the fact that they should work together, then you have an issue to take up with either your LightwaveRF company or else the LED light company. Probably easier to dump this problem, then, on LightwaveRF's lap.)

Comment: @jonk thanks for the info. I've ordered a resistive load so will give that a go. Will post back with the results. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ended up buying a Resloade load resistor and then wiring it between the 'live' and 'neutral' of the dimmer switch and this sorted the issue out correctly. Thought I would post back in case it helps someone else.